# Enabling dual boot of windows after rewriting MBR with GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

Some time ago I had two operating systems on my hard disk, Windows Vista and Windows 8 and I could double boot them. Windows vista was installed on the active partition (C:\ drive). Then I formatted the C drive (Vista partition) and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it. Now I have GRUB on my MBR but I can't log in to Windows 8. To fix this I tried running bootrec.exe /fixmbr from the windows recovery console and it just made things worse. I lost grub, and then I could not log in to any operating systems and had to re install Ubuntu after that.

I want to boot Windows 8 also from it besides Ubuntu. How can I do it? I don't want to risk losing any of my data or installations, so please help me out. Complete information about the hard disk and installed OSs can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7445519/. Thank you very much. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT1: I tried the boot-repair utility. It created two new entries in the GRUB menu. One of them is my Windows Vista recovery drive (ignore it) and the other one is Windows 8 that I want to boot in to on /dev/sda5. Here's the complete report from that tool: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7445554/

Comment: finally problem is you cant boot into windows? and you have ubuntu installed.

Comment: Have you tried running fixboot as well as fixmbr from the recovery console?  fixmbr re-writes the master boot record, while fixboot writes a new partition boot sector to the system partition.

Comment: @Gerowen. Yes I also did that when I ran fixmbr but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try boot repair whit sudo apt-get type:

```
         sudo apt-get-repository boot-repair && sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

follow the instruction it could might work.

Comment: Yes I tried it and now it gives me two new options in the GRUB menu. Seems like it recognized the OS on my windows 8 drive. But when I choose that option it doesn't do anything. Just a cursor blinks on the screen. Here's the information it gave me: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7445554/

Comment: Could you try to enter in the terminal: sudo grub-reconf